# cloudera manager agent installation failed

Tags: cloudera

I get the following error while installing Cloudera Manager:

> Error: Package:
>   cloudera-manager-agent-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el7.x86_64
>   (cloudera-manager) Requires: httpd Error: Package:
>   cloudera-manager-agent-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el7.x86_64
>   (cloudera-manager) Requires: MySQL-python Error: Package:
>   cloudera-manager-agent-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el7.x86_64
>   (cloudera-manager) Requires: mod_ssl

Comment: am new to cloudera environment am getting installation failed.. repo problem what should i do? any one help me out plz

Answer (score 0):

It's saying you should install the prerequisite packages.  Try running:

```
# yum install httpd MySQL-python mod_ssl
```

then retry your install.

Comment: thanks for your response                                                                                                         installled everything even showing same error

Comment: If you run `rpm -qa` do you see httpd, MySQL-python and mod_ssl?